# How do I schedule a python script using cron on OS X Catalina

Tags: python-3.x, cron, macos-catalina

So i'm trying to setup a cron job in Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.3.  For some reason I can get my python script running.  I setup a test job under it and that one works perfectly.

```
* * * * * python3 /Users/eric/Dropbox/python/Print/New\ Orders/funcs.py
* * * * * echo 'hello' >> //Users/eric/Desktop/test/test.txt
``

the echo is running every minute but for some reason I cant the the python file to run.
```

Comment: Try using a full path to python3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest option is the put the full path to the script. For your specific case you can find it by executing `which python3`.
In alternative, you can add the PATH definition into your crontab, e.g.,

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/Users/abc/path/to/python
```

Also, you could redirect the stdout and stderr to some file to have a clearer view of what's going on

```
* * * * * python3 /Users/eric/Dropbox/python/Print/New\ Orders/funcs.py 1>/tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log
```