# Crontab syntax settings for OS X Catalina

Tags: python, macos, cron

I have the same issue and tried the fix from 
[How do I schedule a python script using cron on OS X Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407554/how-do-i-schedule-a-python-script-using-cron-on-os-x-catalina) and crontab still does not execute python.  It will execute other crons.  Below is what my Mac listed.

whereis python command:

`/usr/bin/python3`

my current crontab:

```
PATH=$PATH:/bin/sh:/usr/bin/python3 

* * * * * python3 /Users/mark/Desktop/crons/test.py 1>/tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log
```

The stderr.log produces:

`/bin/sh: python3: command not found`

The stdout.log produces nothing.

Since the stderr.log looked for python3 in `/bin/sh` that was where I figured I needed to change the path?

Comment: Try just saying `/usr/bin/python3 /Users/mark/Desktop/crons/test.py 1>/tmp/stdout.log 2>/tmp/stderr.log` without having `python3` in the PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Noah, that fix didn't work.